# A circus tent is cylindrical to a height of $3$ meters and conical above it.

Tags: geometry

> A circus tent is cylindrical to a height of $3$ m and conical above it. If it's diameter is $105$ m and slant height of the conical portion is $53$ m, calculate the length of the canvas $5$ m wide to make the required tent.

What I've tried is in the picture:

[image]

Comment: And what's the problem? S = surface area of ​​the cylinder + cone; length of the canvas = S/5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tent consists of two shapes, a cylinder and a cone. You need the lateral surface area (excluding the circles) of both. Look up the formulas and simply plug in the given numbers. Then divide the sum by 5.